# Java - Increase the value of an int size method by 1 everytime the method is called

Tags: java, arrays, count, field, addition

I'm stuck on this one question I can't get my head around. I need to write a method to increase the number of "votes" of a specific "act" by one and then print out the updated vote count for that specific act. I'm working with ArrayLists here as well to point out.

Comment: whats the problem you have faced?

Comment: clear your arraylist before call then whenever u start method they clear and new data are avail new arrylist

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic you want to follow:

1: Iterate through ArrayList of 'acts'

2: Check for specified 'act'

3: If 'act' equals specified 'act', add one to your counter variable (votes++)

This is as much information as I'll give out without code to show what you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map:

```
Class VoteCounter {

   Map<Integer, Integer> actToCounterMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();


   public void raiseVoteForAct(int actId) {
       if (actToCounterMap.contains(actId) {
         int curVote = actToCounterMap.get(actId);
         curVote++;
          actToCounterMap.put(actId, curVote);
       } else {
          // init to 1
          actToCounterMap.put(actId, 1);
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print entire objects out in java, such as

```
System.out.println("Array list contains: " + arrayListName);
```

which will print the contents of the array without iterating through each value, although it may have odd syntax. As for the "acts", which I assume you mean objects, if you want to iterate the number of votes by one, you can have a class like this:

```
public class Act{
    int votes = 0;

    public void increaseVote(){
        votes ++;
        //You can also do votes = votes + 1, or votes += 1, but this is the fastest.
    }

    //While were at it, let's add a print method!
    pubic void printValue(){
        System.out.println("Votes for class " + this.getClass().getName() + " = " + votes + ".");
    }
}
```

Finally, for a class with the arrayList:

```
class classWithTheArrayList {
    private ArrayList<Act> list = new ArrayList<Act>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Act example1 = new Act();

        list.add(example1); 
        //ArrayLists store a value but can't be changed 
        //when in the arraylist, so, after updating the value like this:

        Act example2 = new Act();
        example2.increaseVote();
        //we need to replace the object with the updated one
        replaceObject(example1, example2);
    }


    public void replaceObject(Object objToBeRemoved, Object objToReplaceWith){
        list.add(objToReplaceWith, list.indexOf(objToBeRemoved); //Add object to the same position old object is at
        list.remove(objToBeRemoved); //Remove old object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more efficient vote counter.

```
class VoteCounter<T> {
   final Map<T, AtomicInteger> actToCounterMap = new HashMap<>();

   public void raiseVoteForAct(T id) {
       AtomicInteger ai = actToCounterMap.get(id);
       if (ai == null)
          actToCounterMap.put(id, ai = new AtmoicInteger());
       ai.incrementAndGet();
   }
}
```

Instead of `AtomicInteger` you can use `new int[1]` but it's relatively ugly. ;)